# Return from doPost() in JSP

Tags: java, http, jsp, rest, servlets

I am trying to implement REST type architecture without using any framework. So I am basically calling a JSP from my client end which is doing a `doPost()` on to the remote server providing services. Now I am able to pass the data from client to server in JSON format but I don know how to read the response. Can someone help me out with this.

Client Side:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ....
    ....
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/test/Login");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    //Send post it as a "json_message" paramter.
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_message", jsonStringUserLogin)); 
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
    HttpResponse fidresponse = client.execute(httpPost);

   ....
   ....
 }
```

Server Side:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  String jsonStringUserLogin = (String)request.getParameter("json_message");
  ....
  ....
  request.setAttribute("LoginResponse", "hello");
  // Here I need to send some string back to the servlet which called. I am assuming 
  // that  multiple clients will be calling this service and do not want to use 
  // RequestDispatcher as I need to specify the path of the servlet. 

  // I am looking for more like return method which I can access through 
  // "HttpResponse" object in the client.

  }
```

I just started with servlets and wanted to implement a REST service by myself. If you have any other suggestion please do share... Thank You,

Comment: Are you asking how to get the json string from request or how to deserialize the json string?

Comment: I want to know how to get a JSON string from request?...from another servlet on a remote computer...

Comment: The response body will contain your json response. Read the response body from the fidresponse. ( I am yet not  sure I understand your question)

Comment: @subirkumarsao I have edited my post. I am basically setting an attribute called "LoginResponse". How do I access this from my fidresponse object?

Answer (score 0):

in doPost you simply have to do :

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8;");
out.println("{\"key\": \"value\"}"); // json type format {"key":"value"}
```

and this will return json data to client or servlet..

reading returned data using jquery ajax ...
on client side using jquery do the following :

```
$.getJSON("your servlet address", function(data) {
                    var items = [];
                    var keys= [];
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        keys.push(key);
                        items.push(val);

                    });
                    alert(keys[0]+" : "+items[0]);           
                });
```

on servlet you know how to read json data

Comment: Is it System.out.println(...) ??

Comment: I actually wanted the JSON back on my client servlet. I tried your solution.It just prints on to the console. Do you know how I can access the value using the key in the client using the fidresponse object?

Comment: PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); this statement will write the data back from where the request is triggered, not on the consol.

Answer (score 0):

After you executed the post you can ready the response like this.

```
HttpEntity entity  = fidresponse.getEntity();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

String l = null;
String rest = "";
while ((l=br.readLine())!=null) {
  rest=rest+l;
}
```

Here rest will contain your json response string.
You can also use StringBuffer.

Comment: What should I do on the server side? Do I just print it?